# How to make set:: find() work for custom class objects?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm a bit confused about using STL `set::find()` for a set of my own defined class objects.

My class contains more than two items (3/4/5 etc.), so how can I overload `less` operator?

I tried for 3 variable, which is as follows and working fine:

```
return( (a1.i < a2.i) ||
    (!(a1.i > a2.i) && (a1.f < a2.f)) ||
    (!(a1.i > a2.i) && !(a1.f > a2.f) && (a1.c < a2.c)));
```

where, `a1`, and `a2` are class objects and (`i`, `f` and `c` are class members).

Now I want to generalize this for n members, but my `find()` does not always work.

I've been looking through STL's detailed documentation, trying to learn how `set::find()` is implemented, and why it needs less (`<`) operator overloading.

I referred to sgi and msdn documentation, but I could not find much about implementation details of `set::find()` there, either.

What am I doing wrong in my `set::find()` implementation?

Comment: Why do you care how `std::set::find` is implemented? Don't you care more about how you are to use it?

Comment: The implementation of find isn't specified, but very tight requirements are specified in the standard. For example, In the C++11 standard, see 23.2.4.

Comment: You can just use a default case of std::set::find and step into the function, whichever compiler you are using.

Comment: The way set is implemented is not defined in the standart. So the details of implementation can be a little bit different from compiler to compiler. But the complexity of the find method must be logarithmic. Usually, set is implemented as a red-black tree.

Comment: Also note that the SGI STL is not the same as the C++ standard library. There are differences in some places, so if you are using standard C++ you should be aware of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a strict ordering of your objects. So if your object is made up of `n` members `a_1` .. `a_n` which all have a strict ordering themselves, what you can do is:

```
bool operator< (const TYPE &rhs) {
  if (a_1 < rhs.a_1) return true; else if (a_1 > rhs.a_1) return false;
  if (a_2 < rhs.a_2) return true; else if (a_2 > rhs.a_2) return false;
  ...
  if (a_n < rhs.a_n) return true;
  return false;
}
```

**Edit:**
If either boost or C++11 is an option for you, you should really go with the `std::tie`/`boost::tie` method Luc Danton suggests in his answer. It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a tuple to easily get an lexicographical ordering of your members:

```
return std::tie(lhs.i, lhs.f, lhs.c) < std::tie(rhs.i, rhs.f, rhs.c);
```

This requires that every member be of a comparable type, e.g. `lhs.i < rhs.i` makes sense.

Note that `std::tie` and `std::tuple` are only available for C++11, so for C++03 you can use e.g. Boost.Tuple which does provide a `boost::tie` (`boost::tuple` uses the same ordering as `std::tuple`).

As to where this should go, it is customary to put that in an `operator<` (after all this is what make the use of `tie` for an easy ordering possible in the first place). Quite often this operator will be a friend, so this would look like:

```
class foo {
public:
    /* public interface goes here */

    // declaration of non-member friend operator
    // if it doesn't need to be a friend, this declaration isn't needed
    friend
    bool operator<(foo const& lhs, foo const& rhs);

private:
    T t;
    U u;
    V v;

};

bool operator<(foo const& lhs, foo const& rhs)
{
    // could be boost::tie
    return std::tie(lhs.t, lhs.u, lhs.v) < std::tie(rhs.t, rhs.u, rhs.v);
}
```

As you can see it's not fully automatic as the implementation of `operator<` needs to list every member of `foo` (or at least those that matter for the ordering), twice. There isn't a better way I'm afraid.

Instead of providing an `operator<` you can specialize `std::less` for `foo` but that's a bit exotic and not the preferred way. If the ordering would still not make sense to be part of the extended interface of `foo` (e.g. there might be more than one ordering that makes sense without a canonical one), then the preferred way is to write a functor:

```
struct foo_ordering {
    bool operator()(foo const& lhs, foo const& rhs) const
    {
        /* implementation as before, but access control/friendship
           has to be planned for just like for operator< */
    }
};
```

Then you'd use e.g. `std::set<foo, foo_ordering>`.

Be aware that no matter what form the ordering takes (through either `operator<`, `std::less<foo>` or a functor) if it is used with an `std::set` or any other associative container (and by default e.g. `std::set<T>` uses `std::less<T>` which in turn uses `operator<` by default) it must follow some stringent criteria, i.e. it must be a strict weak ordering. However if all the members that are used for the `foo` ordering themselves have SW orderings then the resulting lexicographical ordering is also a SW ordering.

Comment: +1 The nicest solution, but I am racking my brains looking at the expression in OP's operator< and I'm not convinced that it's equivalent to yours :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza As advertised this provides a lexicographical ordering. Whether the OP needs that or not I can't quite tell either :)

Answer (score 2):

std::set element comparison function should define Strict Weak Ordering relation on elements domain. Using this definition we can say that two elements are equivalent if compare( a, b ) is false and compare( b, a ) is false too. std::find can be implemented using this assumption.
You can find more here: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html and http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator <` should be capable to compare every object with given one, like that

```
struct Data
{
    bool operator < (const Data& right) const
    {
    return( (this.i < right.i) ||
        (!(this.i > right.i) && (this.f < right.f)) ||
        (!(this.i > right.i) && !(this.f > right.f) && (this.c < right.c)));
    }
}
```

Also, your compare algorithm looks doubtful, because it doees not consider cases, when

```
this.i == right.i
```

or

```
this.f == right.f
```

And you actually should not be interested in `std::set` implementation. It can change from compiler to compiler and can be modified in future. Your program should make assumptions only about container *interface*, never *implementation*.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but a detailed documentation of STL can be found on [the website of SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).

Comment: There are actually a fair number of differences between the SGI STL and what's in the standard library. Something like cppreference.com is probably a better idea, or if someone is up to learning standardese they can just use the standard directly: see n3337, linked from [this page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/#mailing2012-01)

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, I understood that *any STL documentation* would do, but I should still have linked to a resource about the standard library itself.